# How to create helper variable in ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use Angular 10 and I have an `*ngFor` directive to iterate over an array of elements as in the example below:

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos();">
    <h3>{{foo.a()}}</h3>
    <h3>{{foo.a()}}</h3>
    <h3>{{foo.a()}}</h3>
</div>
```

As in the example shown above `foo.a()` is used several times, but this call takes a few milliseconds. Is there any fast way to temporarily store the value and use `fooA` instead? I was hoping something as `ngFor="let foo of foos(); let fooA = foo.a()"` would work, which doesn't. What is the fastest way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not be doing any function calls like this in the dom, but if you must you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos();">
    <ng-container *ngIf="foo.a() as fooA">
        <h3>{{ fooA }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ fooA }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ fooA }}</h3>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get around this at the moment, I was thinking of `<ng-container` as well, but it introduces another layer which slows down. But it seems, thats my last hope

Comment: Perhaps look into using ngOnChanges to run foos(), and foo.a().